# How can I see my original source code on the server Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, phabricator

I'm a novice in Mercurial and Phabricator.

I cannot see my source code on the server repository. 
How can I see my original source code on my Mercurial repository? 
I mean that if I want to compile the code on the server, which files will be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't manipulate files directly in repository as *files* (they doesn't exist as FS-object) - and this is true for all and any SCM.
You have to extract files from repository as unversioned tree into some location (`hg help archive`) or have Working Directory with files (`hg help up`), because usually servver-side repositories are "bare", with empty Working Directory.

Best (and standard) way to do it - use **server-side** [hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html)